# How to get "validated Body" and "authenticated user" in a request of a NestJS Controller Handler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I working with a [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) application that uses ["AuthGuard" with 'jwt' strategy.](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#jwt-functionality)

I would like to receive an authenticated `POST` from the user.

So I added the `@Request() request` decorated attribute then i get `request.user` to get the user. as describe [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#implement-protected-route-and-jwt-strategy-guards)

I also added the `@Body() body` decorated attribute to get the body.

But I noticed that I cannot use both. Only the first one is defined.

For instance if I define `@Body() body` first::

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })
public create(@Body() body, @Request() request) {
    console.log(body); // { name: 'test'}
    console.log(request); //undefined
}
```

and if I define `@Request() request` first:

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })
public create(@Request() request, @Body() body) {
    console.log(body); // undefined
    console.log(request); //  {name: 'test'}
}
```

And Without Body and validation

```
@Post()
public create(@Request() request) {
    console.log(request); //  {name: 'test'}
}
```

How can I get the authenticated user and the validated body from the same request in this Handler?

Strange that `@Request() request` is actually returning the Body, not the request itself

Obs, Why do I not use `request.body` ? because of a custom validation pipe.

Comment: What happens when you do `@Body(ValidationPipe) body: any`? I think what is happening is that the validation pipe is trying to run against both variables in the controller instead of just the one you want it to. Your other option is to create a custom decorator to return `req.user`. You can [learn more about that here](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)

Comment: I tried but with same effect. I tried to remove body also, and noticed that the "Request" actually gives me the body .. I dont know if I am doing something very wrong.

Comment: Do you have a repository with this being reproduced? I'm pretty sure somewhere in the docs it has mentioned not to use library specific approaches (i.e. `@Request()` or `@Response()`) cause it makes some features not work correctly (like interceptors) so I wonder if that is the problem

Comment: I just was able to isolate and locate the point of failure, was not in this code above.
I had two controllers into two different folders with same name `ListController` and the same method `create()`. For some reason the definition of one method was interering into another method. I just renamed the controller class and it works. I realy dont know why this happens, but it happesn. I will try to figure it out and maybe ask a specific question about it.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244179/nestjs-a-method-handler-is-interfering-into-another-handler-with-same-name-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit confused but pretty sure you need to add the AuthGuard to enable to auth middlewares

```
@AuthGuard(JwtGuard)
@Controller()
export class TestContoller {
  @Post('something')
  doTheThing(@Body(new ValidationPipe) body: SomeModelDTO, @Req() request): User {
     return request.user;
  }
}
```

- User will probably only be set in the auth middleware if you've created a guard correctly etc.
- Validation pipe requires a class/DTO with class-validator metadata applied to properties

Example DTO

```
export class SomeModelDTO {
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  arr: string[];
}
```