# NestJS - A method handler is interfering into another handler with same name in another controller

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I had two controllers into two differnt folders into two different modules, Both of them has a method with same `create` name.

`/admin/entity.controller.ts`

```
@Controller("admin")
export class EntityController{
    @Post()
    public async create(@Request() request: any): Promise<List> {
        console.log("request", request) // Logs the Body {"name": "test"} instead of request.
    }
}
```

`/user/entity.ontroller.ts`

```
@Controller("user")
export class EntityController{
    @Post()
    public async create(@Body() entity: Entity) {
        console.log("entity", entity) // logs the body {"name": "test"}
    }
}
```

When I do post the following in both routes: `{"name": "test"}`,

It happens that `admin` `create()` method logs the `body` part, not the `requests` as expected.

It seems to be that the definition of the `user` controller is interfering into the `admin` controller and making it to do not work properly.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding the `EntityController` depending on how Nest pulls in the dependencies. Change the name of one of the classes. `AdminController` `UserController` or something

Comment: Why this happens? I must clarify that they are also on different modules .

Comment: That may help. I've named my classes the same thing. It makes it too confusing when following a stack trace. Even in Object Oriented Programming it's considered bad practice and an anti-pattern to re-use a class name.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/789) in NestJS, which will be [fixed](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/6141) in version [8.0.0](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/6349).

Nest currently uses class *names* to identify providers/controllers/injectables. The fix uses class *references* instead.